# Where can one find list of keyboard shortcuts for powershell?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

Where can one find the complete list of keyboard shortcuts for the last version of Powershell terminal (windows 10)?

I've been googling for an hour and the best I found were:

- [ISE Shortcuts](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/01/29/the-complete-list-of-powershell-ise-3-0-keyboard-shortcuts/) - which is not for Powershell terminal
- [This one](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows10GetsAFreshCommandPromptAndLotsOfHotkeys.aspx) - which is not complete
- [The last one](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-keyboard.html) - which is old

Comment: How do you know the list from Scott is not complete?

Comment: @ShawnMelton `Ctrl+F` and `Ctrl+M` do not work for example. And `ctrl+space` is not listed in his list for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*As always for me. You can spend a whole day trying to solve an issue or find an answer, but as soon as you ask someone's help, the solution will be found in five minutes by yourself.*

As things turned out, there is a module PSReadline installed by default in Windows 10. So some of shortcuts (e.g. `ctrl+M` and `ctrl+F`) do not work. But one can find easily all of new shortcuts. Just type in terminal `Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler` or `Ctrl+Alt+?` to get the complete list of shortkeys for powershell terminal

Thanks to this post [Console extension PSReadline now part of PowerShell 5 in Windows 10](https://4sysops.com/archives/console-extension-psreadline-now-part-of-powershell-5/).

Comment: Is there a function to show the Windows shortcuts in PS? To show shortcuts such as Win +B for bottom right task list or Win + P for Projector or F11 for fullscreen?